# How to set active class to the menu of any page coming from a single.php template

Tags: menus

I have a static bootstrap menu in header.php with elements as follow:

```
<li> <a href="about-fundation.php">About Fundation</a>
</li>
```

I want that every page derived from single.php gets the active class for the li element. Example of the code in single.php

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if ( in_category('events') ) {
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_events.php'); }
```

Example of the resulting pages:
website/2017/09/18/Name-of-the-event/

I'm already using (for certain menus):

```
<?php if (is_page('about-fundation')) echo 'active'; ?>
```

which does not work for these singlepage derived pages.

Comment: you are not dealing with (static) pages, but seem to be targeting a single post; review https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

Comment: It works great!! Thank you!! using:
<?php if(is_single()) echo 'active'; ?>
This is my first question in stakexchange, how do I give you an accepted answer or reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Here is the answer:

```
<?php if(is_single()) echo 'active'; ?>
```